# Access to Configuration object from Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to access to the Active Directory from my company in many controllers from my ASP.NET vNext project, and I inserted the domain name into my config.json file, so I can access it from the Configuration class. I find it heavy to always instantiate a new Configuration object at every time I want to access to my config.json, is there any way through the `IConfiguration` API to access to the Configuration class initialized into the Startup class ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An example of how you can do this:

Let's assume you have a config.json like below:

```
{
    "SomeSetting1": "some value here",
    "SomeSetting2": "some value here",
    "SomeSetting3": "some value here",
    "ActiveDirectory": {
        "DomainName": "DOMAIN-NAME-HERE"
    }
}
```

Create a POCO type having your option information:

```
public class ActiveDirectoryOptions
{
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
}
```

In Startup.cs, when configuring services:

```
services.Configure<ActiveDirectoryOptions>(optionsSetup =>
{
    //get from config.json file
    optionsSetup.DomainName = configuration.Get("ActiveDirectory:DomainName");
});
```

In all controllers which want to get this config setting, do something like...Here the options is injected by the DI system:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<ActiveDirectoryOptions> _activeDirectoryOptions;

    public HomeController(IOptions<ActiveDirectoryOptions> activeDirectoryOptions)
    {
        _activeDirectoryOptions = activeDirectoryOptions;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string domainName = _activeDirectoryOptions.Options.DomainName;

        ........
    }
}
```

---

**Responding to the comment:**

> Dependency Injection was one of my option, but assume that you inject many repository inside your controller and a UserManager object because you want some user management, your constructor will be very busy. And all the time you want to use your controller, an IOptions object will be instanciate, but what if you just want to use this object in one method of your controller ?

There are couple of options that I can think of:

1. From within the action, you can do

   `var options = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ActiveDirectoryOptions>>().Options;`
2. You can have a parameter to the action which is decorated with `FromServicesAttribute`. This attribute will cause the parameter value to be retrieved from the DI.
   Example:

   `public IActionResult Index([FromServices] IOptions<ActiveDirectoryOptions> options)`

I prefer #2 over #1 as in case of unit testing it gives you information on all dependent pieces.

Comment: Dependency Injection was one of my option, but assume that you inject many repository  inside your controller and a UserManager object because you want some user management, your constructor will be very busy. And all the time you want to use your controller, an IOptions object will be instanciate, but what if you just want to use this object in one method of your controller ?

Comment: @ChrisProlls: I updated my answer above with details related to your comment.

Comment: The #2 works very nice :) Thanks !  I tried the #1 but it needs an HttpContext object for using RequestServices method, it's not a static method. Before, we could use System.Web to retrieve the current HttpContext, but with ASP.NET vNext the System.Web namespace doesn't exist anymore. So how can I find the current HttpContext ?

Comment: You can inject IHttpContextAccessor. There is no equivalent of HttpContext.Current