# What is the right way of accessing configuration from, say, config.json outside of Startup class?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, asp.net-core

What is the right way of accessing configuration from, say, config.json outside of Startup class? Do we need to create new Configuration() everytime we need to access configuration, like this?

```
Configuration = new Configuration()
    .AddJsonFile("config.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my reply over here. Basically you can use DI to get access to the configuration.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28953315/1184056