# Unable to get user secret from confiuration manager in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings, system.configuration

I'm currently setting up a .net core web application, and have set up MailKit to handle it's email sending.

Rather than hard coding my smtp password I went with the user secret option.  However for some reason every time I try to retrieve the password, it comes back as null.
The Error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: password
>   MoveNext in MessageServices.cs, line 56

I was wondering if anyone can see what I'm missing!

Here is my MessageService.cs

```
    public class AuthMessageSender : IEmailSender, ISmsSender
{

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public AuthMessageSender()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message, string fullName)
    {

        try
        {
            var _email = "info@*******.co.uk";
            var _epass = Configuration["AdminPassword:Email"];
            var _dispName = "Mark ****";
            var myMessage = new MimeMessage();
            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            myMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(fullName ?? "User", email));
            myMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_dispName, _email));
            myMessage.Subject = subject;
            builder.HtmlBody = message;
            myMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                bool UseSSL = true;
                string Host = "just22.justhost.com";
                int Port = 465;
                await smtp.ConnectAsync(Host, Port, UseSSL).ConfigureAwait(true);
                smtp.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                smtp.Authenticate(_email, _epass); // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                await smtp.SendAsync(myMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await smtp.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


}

    public Task SendSmsAsync(string number, string message)
    {
        // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

And here is my Start.cs

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseIdentity();

        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
        {
            AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"],
            AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"]
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        await CreateRoles(context, serviceProvider);
    }
    private async Task CreateRoles(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        // Create a list of roles with both name and normalised name attributes
        List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>();
        roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" });
        roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Member", NormalizedName = "MEMBER" });
        roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "Moderator", NormalizedName = "MODERATOR" });
        // Check if the role already exists
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
            if (!roleExist)
            {   // Add it if it doesn't
                context.Roles.Add(role);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("mark****@gmail.com");
        if (user != null)
        {
            var gotRoles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            if (!gotRoles.Equals("Admin"))
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked to make sure the secret exists, which it does, along with Facebook Authentication secrets, which seem to work just fine.

If I hard code the password, the email gets sent.  When I set break points I can see that the password is indeed null. I'm a bit stumped!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your configuration is public? I'm not really sure how we could be of help here... you could try pulling the user secret elsewhere, like where you're utilizing the one in your config file.  just set a break point and see if it gets set there.  Otherwise, make sure you're spelling it correctly.  If the user secret does indeed exist, there shouldn't be any reason that one would work, and one wouldn't.

Comment: @Krinter Thanks for help!  When I tried getting the secret from within the StartUp.cs I found it was accessible, which then lead me to look at the builder code I used in AuthMessageSender, I copied it from Startup.cs exactly, and added the variable assignment in the same block, which worked a treat. I'll add my answer now, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

New Answer based on information provided by @Kritner and this Link: [Access to Configuration object from Startup class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897372/access-to-configuration-object-from-startup-class/28953315#28953315)

First I created a POCO that had ALL of my SMTP properties that should be out of sight, like so:

```
        public class SmtpConfig
{
    public string EmailDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string SmtpPassworrd { get; set; }
    public string SmtpUserEmail { get; set; }
    public string SmtpHost { get; set; }
    public int SmtpPort { get; set; }
}
```

Then in My Startup.cs I added this to ConfigureServices:

```
            services.Configure<SmtpConfig>(optionsSetup =>
        {
            //get from appsetings.json file
            optionsSetup.SmtpPassworrd = Configuration["SMTP:Password"];
            optionsSetup.SmtpUserEmail = Configuration["SMTP:Email"];
            optionsSetup.SmtpHost = Configuration["SMTP:Host"];
            optionsSetup.SmtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["SMTP:Port"]);
        });
```

Finally I edited my messageServices to look like this:

```
        public class AuthMessageSender : IEmailSender, ISmsSender
{
    private readonly IOptions<SmtpConfig> _smtpConfig;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public AuthMessageSender( IOptions<SmtpConfig> smtpConfig)
    {
        _smtpConfig = smtpConfig;
    }
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message, string fullName)
    {

        try
        {
            var _email = _smtpConfig.Value.SmtpUserEmail;
            string _epass = _smtpConfig.Value.SmtpPassworrd;
            var _dispName = _smtpConfig.Value.EmailDisplayName;
            var myMessage = new MimeMessage();
            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            myMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(fullName ?? "User", email));
            myMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_dispName, _email));
            myMessage.Subject = subject;
            builder.HtmlBody = message;
            myMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                bool UseSSL = true;
                string Host = _smtpConfig.Value.SmtpHost;
                int Port = _smtpConfig.Value.SmtpPort;
                await smtp.ConnectAsync(Host, Port, UseSSL).ConfigureAwait(true);
                smtp.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                smtp.Authenticate(_email, _epass); // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                await smtp.SendAsync(myMessage).ConfigureAwait(true);
                await smtp.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

Comment: rather than rebuilding your configuration in all the classes that need it, consider utilizing the solution provided in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28953315/2312877 Basically, you'll be creating an injectable object that will hold your configurations, this way you can inject the settings into your classes, rather than rebuilding them - which will make for easier to understand code, as well as easier to test.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thank you! I just found a need to access the information in my app settings again, so this is going to help with performance and debugging! I have now in fact moved all of my smtp settings into my user secrets (user email, host etc) and my code looks much cleaner with no exposed information!